# How can I add JavaFX platform to NetBeans IDE

Tags: javafx

I want to use JavaFX with NetBeans, but when I create new project and select JavaFX there is no option for javafx application as all have said to select. It has few other option and when I open any one among them then it show that doesnt contain JavaFX. What should I do?

Comment: Either you do not have a version of Java installed that has JavaFX with it, or you are using an old version of Netbeans.  I recommend upgrading.

Comment: I have NetBeans 8.0 and Java 7.

Comment: My File -> New Project -> JavaFX has a "JavaFX Application" entry listed.  Yours should too.  If it is not there, then there has to be something wrong with your installation.

Comment: Got it ! Updating both really help.